# How to move Ubuntu from one SSD to another

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

I have a standard 256 GB SSD on my laptop, recently I bought another 1 TB SSD.
On my old SSD, I have dual boot Windows 10 + Ubuntu.

I would like to migrate Ubuntu on the new SSD (1TB) and allocate 500GB to it. Other 500GB (2nd SSD) I want to merge with 256GB (1st SSD) for Windows.

I was curious whether it is a good idea or not, to split the second SSD in this way?
Also, I would be grateful for a good guide for it.

Comment: You cannot merge, but can use as a data partition. But do a new clean install to new drive in UEFI boot mode. Make sure drive is gpt and has ESP - efi system partition, even though grub will install to ESP on Windows drive. Then restore from your backups. Great way to confirm your backups are complete as you still have old install to go back and add any missing info. UEFI/gpt partitioning in Advance, new versions do not need swap partition:
http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu

Comment: I was curious whether I should/shouldn't move the Ubuntu to a new SSD, or both systems could stay on the first SSD and I can simply allocate space from new SSD to Windows and Ubuntu (like 500gb to one and 500gb to another). Will, I got any limitations/problems with this way?

Comment: Many with one SSD and one HDD, have both installs on one system and use other for data. With two similar speed drives, I prefer to have each system on separate drives. And if space, can backup some critical data to other drive, but still need full backups to another drive or location. But if installing Ubuntu to separate drive, often best to disconnect Windows drive either physically or logically in UEFI. Be sure new drive is gpt and Ubuntu is installed in UEFI mode.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI